# How to use Python and libraries with Conda in Atom?

Tags: python, matplotlib, anaconda, atom-editor, miniconda

I make use of miniconda for data science projects. For this its normal to make use of Jupyter Notebook.

However I want to make some python projects using the IDE Atom. I managed to link to "python.exe" in the miniconda3 folder with Atom. However now I want to make use of libraries such as Matplotlib, Pygame, Pandas etc. How do I do this?

Usually it would be as easy as "pip install matplotlib" or "conda install matplotlib", but this does not seem to work. I tried creating an environment with "conda create --prefix ./env matplotlib" but this also does not seem to be working... What am I missing?

Comment: if atom is configured to use the correct conda environment, all of the packages in that environment should come with it

Comment: i would presume that `conda install package` is sufficient...  i just use `vscode` and install what i need, which is very light weight python usage.

Comment: Probably not a good thing to invest your time in because Atom is being discontinued on Dec 15, 2022. [Sunsetting Atom](https://github.blog/2022-06-08-sunsetting-atom/)

Answer (score 1):

OK thanks guys. I changed to Pycharm instead of Atom and used this tutorial, which helped me a lot https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hVcEv7rEN24&t=320s. Am I allowed to post a link?

**Solution**

1. I created an environment in my folder C:\Users\Searching_Badger\Documents\Sample_Project1 using Conda Create --prefix ./env
2. I activated that environment using Conda Activate ./env
3. I installed the libraries I wanted using Conda Install Matplotlib Numpy Pandas
4. I started PyCharm and opened the folder 1. C:\Users\Searching_Badger\Documents\Sample_Project1 , this automatically selected the correct python interpreter in this environment which is *C:\Users\Searching_Badger\Documents\Sample_Project1\env*python.exe
5. I create a .py file that uses matplotlib in the project folder such as C:\Users\Searching_Badger\Documents\Sample_Project1\test.py

This seems to work for PyCharm at least.